# Copy all sheets of a workbook into destination sheet under eachother excell vba

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm searching for a way to copy all sheets of a workbook into a destination sheet in the same workbook, under eachother.
Every sheets contain 1 column of names, and they need to be pasted under eachother in a destination sheet. + in the destination folder the sheet name has to be pased next to each name in the second column. For example:

**Sheet1**:

xxx

erer

zerzeerz

er

**Sheet2**:

sfd

klm

zzzer

**Destinationsheet:**

xxx      sheet1

erer     sheet1

zerzeerz sheet1

er        sheet1

sfd      sheet2

klm      sheet2

zzzer    sheet2

I'm not good in vba, and tried many things on the internet, but nothing works.
Does somebody have an idea

Comment: You should post whatever you've tried .

Comment: Welcome to SO! Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the most effective coding help on SO. As written, this question will most likely be closed and receive *very little* attention - especially without any of your own coding efforts posted.

Comment: What have you searched for? This is a pretty common request, so I'd be very surprised if you didn't find anything that can help get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for column **A** in the source sheets into column **A** and **B** of the destination sheet:

```
Sub columnIzer()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, d As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, M As Long
    Dim rn1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Set d = Sheets("Destinationsheet")

    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name <> d.Name Then
            N = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng1 = sh.Range("A1:A" & N)
            M = d.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Set rng2 = d.Range("A" & M)
            rng1.Copy rng2
            rng2.Offset(0, 1).Resize(N, 1).Value = sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to add, I'd qualify the `Rows.count` to match the sheet whose rows you expect to count.

Comment: @BruceWayne .......interesting comment...............in this case, however, `Rows.Count` will always yield **1048576** unless an old version of Excel is being used.

Comment: Ah, yeah true. I'm just so used to qualifying it is a quick flag in my head. If it's an older version, then that'll just return the last row still though, yeah? (It's just not 1048576)

Comment: @BruceWayne  I agree that using qualification is a good practice.